# How to get Mouse Cursor Position on Form in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey, mousemove, onmousemove

I've built a simple `Form` using the [DelphiFMX GUI Library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python). The Form has a `MouseMove` event attached to it.

What I basically want is the `X` and `Y` coordinates of the mouse on the Form when you move the mouse around and then display the coordinates in the `Caption` of the `Form`.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Width = 800
        self.Height = 500
        self.Caption = "Mouse Position: <X, Y>"

        self.MouseMove = self.FormMouseMoveEvent

    def FormMouseMoveEvent(self, sender, e):
        self.Caption = "Mouse Position: <" + e.X + ", " + e.Y + ">"


def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

The Form's caption never changes and always just say "Mouse Position: <X, Y>"

---

UPDATE:

I think the `MouseMove` event isn't being triggered as it should. I've changed the code to the following, but the Caption still isn't updating:

```
def FormMouseMoveEvent(self, sender, e):
    self.Caption = "Just changing the caption"
```

[image: Python blank GUI App]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to correct the way you're triggering the MouseMove Event. It should be `self.OnMouseMove`, which is similar to the `self.OnClose` or any other events like `self.button1.OnClick`. Also, the MouseMove event takes 3 arguments - `Shift`, `X`, and `Y` other than `sender` itself. The `X` and `Y` are of `Single` type in Delphi, which needs to be converted to `String` type.

Here's the fixed code:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Width = 800
        self.Height = 500
        self.Caption = "Mouse Position: <X, Y>"

        self.onMouseMove = self.FormMouseMoveEvent

    def FormMouseMoveEvent(self, sender, Shift, X, Y):
        self.Caption = "Mouse Position: <" + str(X) + ", " + str(Y) + ">"


def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that 'X and Y' coordinates that are returned by *MouseMoveEvent* are integers but the self.Caption expects a string:
You can rewrite the FormMouseMoveEvent() as:

```
def FormMouseMoveEvent(self, sender, e):
    self.Caption = "Mouse Position: <" + str(e.X) + ", " + str(e.Y) + ">"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. I did try this as well.